# what does cannot call non-function withdraw (type int) mean?

Tags: go

I created this program

```
package main

import "fmt"

var bankAccount = 12342

func withdraw(withdrawAmnt int) int { //withdraw function, return int
    bankAccount -= withdrawAmnt
    if bankAccount < 0 {
        bankAccount += withdrawAmnt //bankaccount cannot go negative
        return 1
    } else { return 0 }
}

func deposit(depositAmnt int) {
    bankAccount += depositAmnt
}

func main() {
    var choice int
    var withdraw int
    var deposit int
    fmt.Printf("%d \n 1. withdraw \n 2. deposit \n 3. exit")
    fmt.Scanln(&choice)
    switch choice {
        case 1:
            fmt.Scanln(&withdraw)
            if withdraw(withdraw) != 0 {
                fmt.Println("Not succesful: not enough money (you're broke)")
            }
        case 2:
            fmt.Scanln(&deposit)
            deposit(deposit)
        case 3:
            os.Exit()
    }
}
```

i keep getting this error: cannot call non-function deposit (type int) and cannot call non-function deposit (type int).

Comment: Note that `return 1 } else { return 0 }` can be shortened to:  `return 1} return 0`.  You never need an 'else' immediately after a return :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means exactly what it says:  You cannot call a non-function. Only functions can be called.

Here:

```golang
            deposit(deposit)
```

You're attempting to call `deposit`, but `deposit` is of type `int`:

```golang
    var deposit int
```

This variable declaration of `deposit` shadows the function of the same name at package scope.

To solve your problem, use a different name for either the variable or the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable name overlap the function name.

Try to change one of them